# Why is the output different when I select the same element using class or id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to animate the green button, however, when I select the green button by specifying its id, I can apply fade in and fade out and it works properly. But when I select it using the class, the HTML[image] code is shown as output in the console. Why are the outputs different even though I am selecting the same element through different identifiers.

Comment: Because ID is unique and CLASS isn't

Comment: @Alon I have added [0] with the when I am using class. I guess it specifies that I am trying to access the first object.

Comment: When you access the 0th element it’s returning a native element. Otherwise it’s a jquery object.